# What is the equivalent of proxy_pass on gke ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, kibana, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I created an ingress on GKE for kibana, and the browser returns 404 (although it works with the original service), and I guess it's because I need to route to the `/app/kibana` endpoint. How can I do that?

This is my ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-proxy
    ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: sha1
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: route
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
  annotations:
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-tls
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /kibana
        backend:
          serviceName: kibana-nodeport
          servicePort: 5601
```

my nodeport service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-nodeport
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5601
  selector:
    k8s-app: kibana
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

the kibana orginial service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    component: kibana
  name: kibana-ext
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    - x.x.x.x/32
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5601
  selector:
    k8s-app: kibana
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**UPDATE:**

When I set Kibana's path to "/*", it works. Otherwise I get 404.

Comment: In your setup with `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`, on which `URL` Kibana is responding correctly: `/`, `/kibana`, `/app/kibana` ? Does the solution posted by user @paltaa solved your issue?

Comment: @DawidKruk In the original service I just go to the root ("/") URL and it redirects me to the /login?next=%2F link which works. Also, I might add that all of my ingress backends are healthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the /* so subpaths will work

```
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /kibana/*
        backend:
          serviceName: kibana-nodeport
          servicePort: 5601
```

Comment: I'm still getting 404, and something suspicious I see is that when I hit the ingress URL in /kibana, it redirects me to /login?next=%2Fkibana%2F

Comment: I changed the kibana.yml to be rewritten to /kibana plus changing to your suggestion and it worked! thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the original issue was resolved by an answer provided by user @paltaa and fixed by original poster:

> I changed the kibana.yml to be rewritten to /kibana plus changing to your suggestion and it worked! thanks – Idan

I wanted to add some additional resources/information and a "guide" that could help when dealing with similar issues.

---

Steps to run Kibana in `GKE` with `ingress-gke`:

> Please remember that this is a basic setup for example purposes only.

- Provision the resources with Helm
- Create an `Ingress` resource
- Change the Healthcheck in GCP Cloud Console (Web UI)
- Test

---

#### Provision the resources with Helm

I used below Github page for a reference when installing:

- *[Github.com: Elastic: Helm-charts: Kibana](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/kibana)*

> Method of spawning this setup could be different but the principles should be the same (values).

Commands used (specific to Helm3):

- `$ helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co`
- `$ helm install es elastic/elasticsearch`
- `$ helm pull elastic/kibana --untar`
- `$ cd kibana/ && nano values.yaml`

The changes made in the `values.yaml` are following:

```sh
healthCheckPath: "/test/app/kibana"
```

```sh
# Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/kibana/config/
# such as kibana.yml
# Will work with http://DOMAIN.NAME/test/
kibanaConfig:
   kibana.yml: |
       server.basePath: /test
       server.rewriteBasePath: true
```

```sh
service:
  type: NodePort # <-- Changed from ClusterIP for ingress-gke
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  port: 5601
  nodePort: ""
  labels: {}
  annotations: {}
```

- `$ helm install ki .`

---

#### Create an `Ingress` resource

I used this `Ingress` resource to have an access to the Kibana:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: ssl-certificate
  rules:
  - host: DOMAIN.NAME
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test/*
        backend:
          serviceName: ki-kibana
          servicePort: 5601
```

**As for the annotations used in the question, please review them as some of them could be specific to `ingress-nginx` and will not work with `ingress-gke`.**

---

After applying this resource I couldn't connect to Kibana because of the path of a Healthcheck created:

- Healthcheck created path (incorrect): `/`
- Healthcheck changed path (correct): `/test/app/kibana`

You can change the Healthcheck by following:

- `GCP Cloud Console (Web UI)` --> `Kubernetes Engine` --> `Services & Ingress` --> `kibana-ingress` --> `backend services (unhealthy)` --> `Health Check` --> `Edit`

[image: Healthcheck]

---

#### Test

After all of above steps you can open a web browser and enter:

- `https://DOMAIN.NAME/test`

and be greeted by Elastic's Web UI.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Load-balancing: Docs: Healthcheck concepts](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts)*
- *[Logz.io: Blog: Deploying the ELK stack on Kubernetes with Helm](https://logz.io/blog/deploying-the-elk-stack-on-kubernetes-with-helm/)*
- *[Elastic.co: Guide: Kibana: Master: Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/settings.html)*